# Left join, sum and count group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: goods, store and pics. In the first table goods titles are stored. In the second - balance of goods in different stocks, in the third - links to goods pictures. So goods has one-to-many connection with store and pics.
Now, I need to get a list of goods with sum of stock rests and count of pictures by one query.
I did it like this:

```
SELECT good.id, good.title, sum(store.rest) AS storerest, count(pics.id) AS picscount 
FROM goods 
LEFT JOIN store ON (goods.id = store.goodid) 
LEFT JOIN pics ON (goods.id = pics.goodid) 
GROUP BY goods.id`
```

All seems ok while good has 0 or 1 picture. But when it has 2 - storerest doubles, and I can't understand why.
What's wrong?

Comment: If you remove your GROUP BY clause you will see why sum(store.rest) is not what you expect.

Comment: If in table `pics` for particular `pics`.`goodid` (row) exists more than one row, then it appears, that mysql as if creates additional-virtual row for each `pics`.`goodid` row. And inserts values from `goods` and `store` tables where `pics`.`goodid` = `store`.`goodid` = `goods`.`id`. And with `sum(store.rest)` simply sums all rows (including fake rows). Here some example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0caa01/1 may help to understand what is happening. For me not so easy to understand...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your issue is that when you have two (or more) `store` rows and two (or more) `pics` rows for a single `goods` row, you end up with the product of all the combinations of rows.

To fix this, do your aggregation before joining:

```
SELECT 
  good.id, 
  good.title, 
  IFNULL(s.storerest, 0) AS storerest, 
  IFNULL(p.picscount, 0) AS picscount
FROM goods 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT goodid, sum(rest) AS storerest
  FROM store
  GROUP BY goodid
) s ON (goods.id = s.goodid) 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT goodid, count(id) AS picscount
  FROM pics
  GROUP BY goodid
) p ON (goods.id = p.goodid)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are joining together table 'goods' with two other tables, where these two other tables have a one-to-many relations to the 'goods' table. When they are joined, a combination of rows will results - so if there are 2 pics then store items are listed twice.

The easiest way to solve this if you first calculate the stats of the sub-tables and then you join them and use distinct counting when counting unique items, so for example you query should really be:

```
SELECT good.id, good.title, sum_rest AS storerest, count(distinct pics.id) AS picscount 
FROM goods 
LEFT JOIN (select goodid, sum(rest) as sum_rest from store) s ON (goods.id = s.goodid) 
LEFT JOIN pics ON (goods.id = pics.goodid) 
GROUP BY goods.id
```

Comment: Please, advice. With subselect from `store` near LEFT JOIN i select only necessary columns, not whole table ?

Comment: @user2360831 - yes, as you see in my above answer, the `store` subselect only uses the `goodid` and `rest` fields and does not care about any other columns (if any) of the `store` table.

Answer (score 2):

First consider the size of the join. If there are two pictures for one good then there will be twice as many rows for this good. Actually the rows will be duplicated but for the picture part. Hence the sum of the store.rest will pick up everything twice. With three pictures you would get three times the output.