# MySQL SELECT with LEFT JOIN & SUM GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

Need some help with mysql select with left join, i tried alot of options, looked up for the answers on stack, but can't solve this problem. I'll be grateful for any help. Thanks.

```
SELECT    profile_main.id,
          profile_main.add_date,
          profile_main.expire_date,
          profile_main.status_begin,
          profile_main.status_expire,
          profile_main.views,
          profile_main.last,
          profile_main.confirm,
          profile_info.name,
          profile_contacts.remains,
          profile_rating.rating
FROM      profile_main
LEFT JOIN profile_info
ON        profile_main.id=profile_info.profile_id
LEFT JOIN profile_contacts
ON        profile_main.id=profile_contacts.profile_id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT profile_rating.profile_id, SUM(profile_rating.rating)
   FROM   profile_rating
GROUP BY  profile_rating.profile_id
          ) profile_rating
ON        profile_main.id=profile_rating.profile_id
WHERE     profile_main.user_id=$user_id
AND       profile_main.deleted=0
```

The problem is `LEFT JOIN` with `profile_rating`. I need `SUM(`profile_rating.rating)

here is the profile_main table. table what saving all profiles
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tUu8.png)

here is the profile_rating table. [edit] This table may not contain all profiles rating, just those wich were rated earlyer

```
id profile_id user_id rating ip_addr         add_date  deleted
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1         16       5     15 111.111.111.111 123432433       0
 2         16       5     17 111.111.111.111 123432433       0
 3         16       5     25 111.111.111.111 123432433       0 
 4         16       5     34 111.111.111.111 123432433       0 
 5         16       5     12 111.111.111.111 123432433       0
```

If something else is needed, i will add it

Comment: what exactly is the problem, is your join not behaving as you expect?

Comment: Use table alias to make query more readable. E.g. `FROM profile_main AS pm...`. Then `SELECT pm.id, pm.add_date...`.

Comment: when i run this query, it's return me "Unknown column 'profile_rating.rating' in 'field list'"

Comment: THANKS for all your answers. Very greatfull ! :) Now this topic closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query looks fine and it is a good idea to join pre-aggregated data, just as you are doing here. (A good habit in order not to mistakenly multiply the aggregates from one table with matches in another.)

But you access the field `profile_rating.rating`, which is not available, because you no longer deal with single record values, but sums. Make an alias name for the sum: `SUM(rating) AS sum_rating` and use that in your select clause.

```
SELECT
  m.id,
  m.add_date,
  m.expire_date,
  m.status_begin,
  m.status_expire,
  m.views,
  m.last,
  m.confirm,
  i.name,
  c.remains,
  r.sum_rating
FROM profile_main m
LEFT JOIN profile_info i ON m.id = i.profile_id
LEFT JOIN profile_contacts c ON m.id = c.profile_id
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    profile_id, 
    SUM(rating) AS sum_rating
  FROM profile_rating
  GROUP BY profile_id
) r ON m.id = r.profile_id
WHERE m.user_id = $user_id
AND m.deleted = 0;
```

I also use table aliases to enhance readaility.

Comment: Thanks alot. This is what i needed. Now it`s working. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Why do you `SELECT` in the `JOIN`?

Just select the fields in your main select:

```
SELECT    profile_main.id,
      profile_main.add_date,
      profile_main.expire_date,
      profile_main.status_begin,
      profile_main.status_expire,
      profile_main.views,
      profile_main.last,
      profile_main.confirm,
      profile_info.name,
      profile_contacts.remains,
      profile_rating.rating,
      profile_rating.profile_id, 
      SUM(profile_rating.rating) AS rating_sum
FROM      profile_main
LEFT JOIN profile_info
ON        profile_main.id=profile_info.profile_id
LEFT JOIN profile_contacts
ON        profile_main.id=profile_contacts.profile_id
LEFT JOIN profile_rating
ON        profile_main.id=profile_rating.profile_id
WHERE     profile_main.user_id=$user_id
AND       profile_main.deleted=0
GROUP BY profile_rating.profile_id
```

So you get your summed rating back as `rating_sum`

Comment: The reason is that we don't want to multiply the ratings sum with the number of matches in the info table. Your query does exactly that, which results in incorrect sums. The original query gets a result row per *info Record* anyway, so puttigs this in your GROUP BY would solve the problem: `GROUP BY profile_main.id, profile_info.id`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below query and let me know if need some thing else so that I can modify-

```
SELECT    profile_main.id,
          profile_main.add_date,
          profile_main.expire_date,
          profile_main.status_begin,
          profile_main.status_expire,
          profile_main.views,
          profile_main.last,
          profile_main.confirm,
          profile_info.name,
          profile_contacts.remains,
          SUM(profile_rating.rating)
FROM      profile_main
LEFT JOIN profile_info
ON        profile_main.id=profile_info.profile_id
LEFT JOIN profile_contacts
ON        profile_main.id=profile_contacts.profile_id
LEFT JOIN profile_rating
ON        profile_main.id=profile_rating.profile_id
WHERE     profile_main.user_id=$user_id
AND       profile_main.deleted=0
GROUP BY profile_main.id
```

Comment: at this query i will get just one profile, and i need to get all profiles from `profile_main` table doesn`t matter whether this profile rated earlyer

Comment: @RossDubrivny: this will provide you all active profiles of given user...please share data if not getting..

Comment: @Zafar Malik: Anyway, the original query was perfect apart from not accessing the sum field correctly, whereas your query gives you the sum of the ratings multiplied with the profile matches in the info table. This is because you are missing the info table in your GROUP BY, and which seems also to be what te OP is complaing about (getting profile the Record rather than the separate info records.) `GROUP BY profile_main.id, profile_info.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar questions has already been answered on SO. You are doing the groupby on your wrong column which is not available, use table alias as shown above answer. Please refer these links :

[SQL Server Query LEFT JOIN, SUM and GROUP BY and I'm stumped!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873205/sql-server-query-left-join-sum-and-group-by-and-im-stumped)

And

[Left join, sum and count group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967160/left-join-sum-and-count-group-by)